Uso de zebra_scanner_plugin Flutter
estoy intentando utilizar la dependencia zebra_scanner_plugin: ^1.1.3 (https://pub.dev/packages/zebra_scanner_plugin) en mi aplicación Flutter (version 3.19.5) siguiendo el ejemplo publicado por el creador, ademas de realizar los 4 pasos que se explican dentro del README de la dependencia. El caso es que siguiendo todos estos pasos, al compilar o generar el APK para Android, en consola obtengo el mensaje adjunto mas abajo.
El equipo para el cual estoy utilizando esta dependencia es: Escáner láser de código de barras para Zebra Symbol, lector de código de barras con Cable USB, DS7708.
He revisado las issues del mismo repositorio encontrando consultas parecidas, pero sin respuestas del creador (https://github.com/sanketwarule/zebra_scanner_plugin/issues).
Agradezco cualquier ayuda y/o comentarios que puedan ayudar.
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:10: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.DCSSDKDefs;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:11: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.DCSScannerInfo;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:12: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.FirmwareUpdateEvent;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:13: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.IDcsSdkApiDelegate;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/ScannerAppEngine.java:5: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.DCSSDKDefs;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/ScannerAppEngine.java:6: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.DCSScannerInfo;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/ScannerAppEngine.java:7: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.FirmwareUpdateEvent;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
public class ZebraScannerEngine implements ScannerAppEngine, IDcsSdkApiDelegate {
                                                             ^
  symbol: class IDcsSdkApiDelegate
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
    private static ArrayList<DCSScannerInfo> mScannerInfoList;
                             ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    private static ArrayList<DCSScannerInfo> mOfflineScannerInfoList;
                             ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:156: error: cannot find symbol
    public List<DCSScannerInfo> getActualScannersList() {
                ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:161: error: cannot find symbol
    public DCSScannerInfo getScannerInfoByIdx(int dev_index) {
           ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:169: error: cannot find symbol
    public DCSScannerInfo getScannerByID(int scannerId) {
           ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:198: error: cannot find symbol
    private void createFlatScannerList(ArrayList<DCSScannerInfo> scannerTreeList) {
                                                 ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:205: error: cannot find symbol
    private void addToScannerList(DCSScannerInfo s) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:217: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
    public DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT setAutoReconnectOption(int scannerId, boolean enable) {
                     ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:241: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
    public boolean executeCommand(DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_COMMAND_OPCODE opCode, String inXML, StringBuilder outXML, int scannerID) {
                                            ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:256: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
    public boolean executeSSICommand(DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_COMMAND_OPCODE opCode, String inXML, StringBuilder outXML, int scannerID) {
                                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:275: error: cannot find symbol
    public void dcssdkEventScannerAppeared(DCSScannerInfo availableScanner) {
                                           ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:284: error: cannot find symbol
    public void dcssdkEventCommunicationSessionEstablished(DCSScannerInfo activeScanner) {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:322: error: cannot find symbol
    public void dcssdkEventFirmwareUpdate(FirmwareUpdateEvent firmwareUpdateEvent) {
                                          ^
  symbol:   class FirmwareUpdateEvent
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:326: error: cannot find symbol
    public void dcssdkEventAuxScannerAppeared(DCSScannerInfo newTopology, DCSScannerInfo auxScanner) {
                                              ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:326: error: cannot find symbol
    public void dcssdkEventAuxScannerAppeared(DCSScannerInfo newTopology, DCSScannerInfo auxScanner) {
                                                                          ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/ScannerAppEngine.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
        void scannerFirmwareUpdateEvent(FirmwareUpdateEvent firmwareUpdateEvent);
                                        ^
  symbol:   class FirmwareUpdateEvent
  location: interface IScannerAppEngineDevEventsDelegate
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/ScannerAppEngine.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
    List<DCSScannerInfo> getActualScannersList();
         ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: interface ScannerAppEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/ScannerAppEngine.java:138: error: cannot find symbol
    DCSScannerInfo getScannerInfoByIdx(int dev_index);
    ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: interface ScannerAppEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/ScannerAppEngine.java:146: error: cannot find symbol
    DCSScannerInfo getScannerByID(int scannerId);
    ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: interface ScannerAppEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/ScannerAppEngine.java:176: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
    DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT setAutoReconnectOption(int scannerId, boolean enable);
              ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/ScannerAppEngine.java:236: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
    boolean executeCommand(DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_COMMAND_OPCODE opCode, String inXML, StringBuilder outXML, int scannerID);
                                     ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/ScannerAppEngine.java:246: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
    boolean executeSSICommand(DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_COMMAND_OPCODE opCode, String inXML, StringBuilder outXML, int scannerID);
                                        ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerPlugin.java:13: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.DCSScannerInfo;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerPlugin.java:14: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.SDKHandler;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerPlugin.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
    public static SDKHandler sdkHandler;
                  ^
  symbol:   class SDKHandler
  location: class ZebraScannerPlugin
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerPlugin.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
    public static ArrayList<DCSScannerInfo> scannerInfoList = new ArrayList<DCSScannerInfo>();
                            ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerPlugin
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ConnectionActivity.java:38: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.BarCodeView;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ConnectionActivity.java:39: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.DCSSDKDefs;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ConnectionActivity.java:51: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
    protected DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_BT_PROTOCOL selectedProtocol;
                        ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ConnectionActivity.java:52: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
    protected DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_BT_SCANNER_CONFIG selectedConfig;
                        ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ConnectionActivity.java:160: error: cannot find symbol
    private void updateBarcodeView(LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams, BarCodeView barCodeView) {
                                                                           ^
  symbol:   class BarCodeView
  location: class ConnectionActivity
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/application/Application.java:8: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.DCSScannerInfo;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/application/Application.java:9: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.SDKHandler;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/application/Application.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    public static SDKHandler sdkHandler;
                  ^
  symbol:   class SDKHandler
  location: class Application
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/application/Application.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
    public static ArrayList<DCSScannerInfo> mScannerInfoList = new ArrayList<DCSScannerInfo>();
                            ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class Application
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/application/Application.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
    public static DCSScannerInfo currentConnectedScanner;
                  ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class Application
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/application/Application.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
    public static DCSScannerInfo lastConnectedScanner;
                  ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class Application
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/AvailableScanner.java:5: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.DCSSDKDefs;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/AvailableScanner.java:6: error: package com.zebra.scannercontrol does not exist
import com.zebra.scannercontrol.DCSScannerInfo;
                               ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/AvailableScanner.java:28: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
    private DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_CONN_TYPES connectionType;
                      ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/AvailableScanner.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
    public AvailableScanner(DCSScannerInfo activeScanner) {
                            ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class AvailableScanner
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/AvailableScanner.java:42: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
    public DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_CONN_TYPES getConnectionType() {
                     ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/AvailableScanner.java:46: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
    public void setConnectionType(DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_CONN_TYPES connectionType) {
                                            ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/helpers/AvailableScanner.java:53: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
    public AvailableScanner(int scannerId, String scannerName, String scannerAddress, boolean isConnected, boolean isAutoReconnection, DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_CONN_TYPES connectionType) {
                                                                                                                                                 ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
        mOfflineScannerInfoList = new ArrayList<DCSScannerInfo>();
                                                ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:86: error: package DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT does not exist
        notifications_mask |= (DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_SCANNER_APPEARANCE.value | DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_SCANNER_DISAPPEARANCE.value);
                                                      ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:86: error: package DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT does not exist
        notifications_mask |= (DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_SCANNER_APPEARANCE.value | DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_SCANNER_DISAPPEARANCE.value);
                                                                                                                      ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:87: error: package DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT does not exist
        notifications_mask |= (DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_SESSION_ESTABLISHMENT.value | DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_SESSION_TERMINATION.value);
                                                      ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:87: error: package DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT does not exist
        notifications_mask |= (DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_SESSION_ESTABLISHMENT.value | DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_SESSION_TERMINATION.value);
                                                                                                                         ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:88: error: package DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT does not exist
        notifications_mask |= (DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_BARCODE.value);
                                                      ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:89: error: package DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT does not exist
        notifications_mask |= (DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_IMAGE.value);
                                                      ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:90: error: package DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT does not exist
        notifications_mask |= (DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_VIDEO.value);
                                                      ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:91: error: package DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT does not exist
        notifications_mask |= (DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_EVENT.DCSSDK_EVENT_BINARY_DATA.value);
                                                      ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:171: error: cannot find symbol
            for (DCSScannerInfo scannerInfo : mScannerInfoList) {
                 ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:191: error: cannot find symbol
            ArrayList<DCSScannerInfo> scannerTreeList = new ArrayList<DCSScannerInfo>();
                      ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:191: error: cannot find symbol
            ArrayList<DCSScannerInfo> scannerTreeList = new ArrayList<DCSScannerInfo>();
                                                                      ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:199: error: cannot find symbol
        for (DCSScannerInfo s :
             ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:208: error: cannot find symbol
            for (DCSScannerInfo aux :
                 ^
  symbol:   class DCSScannerInfo
  location: class ZebraScannerEngine
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:218: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
        DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT ret;
                  ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:223: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
        return DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT.DCSSDK_RESULT_FAILURE;
                         ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:246: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
            DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT result = Application.sdkHandler.dcssdkExecuteCommandOpCodeInXMLForScanner(opCode, inXML, outXML, scannerID);
                      ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:247: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
            if (result == DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT.DCSSDK_RESULT_SUCCESS)
                                    ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:249: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
            else if (result == DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT.DCSSDK_RESULT_FAILURE)
                                         ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:261: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
            DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT result = Application.sdkHandler.dcssdkExecuteSSICommandOpCodeInXMLForScanner(opCode, inXML, outXML, scannerID);
                      ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:262: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
            if (result == DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT.DCSSDK_RESULT_SUCCESS)
                                    ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:264: error: package DCSSDKDefs does not exist
            else if (result == DCSSDKDefs.DCSSDK_RESULT.DCSSDK_RESULT_FAILURE)
                                         ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:274: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
/Users/usuario/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/zebra_scanner_plugin-1.1.3/android/src/main/java/com/androsys/zebra_scanner_plugin/ZebraScannerEngine.java:279: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^

